# How can I "re-enable" cognito tokens coming from other tab?

Tags: typescript, iframe, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have this feature that opens another tab in a different domain, but I need the cognito session to remain, so I created a hidden iframe to have the same origin. I am using something like this to move the local storage:

```
const proxy = document.getElementById('proxyDashboard');
if (this.isIFrame(proxy) && proxy.contentWindow) {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){
    proxy.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({key, value: localStorage.getItem(key)}), 'http://localhost:4200');
  });
  console.log(this.dashboardUrl);
  window.open(this.dashboardUrl, '_blank');
  
}
```

Then in the other side I'm getting the tokens like this:

```
constructor(){
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage.bind(this), false);
  } else {
    (<any>window).attachEvent('onmessage', this.receiveMessage.bind(this));
  }
}

receiveMessage: any = (event: any) =>  {
  if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:4201') {
    return;
  }
  const payload = JSON.parse(event.data);
  localStorage.setItem(payload.key, JSON.stringify(payload.value));
}
```

The issue now is, how can I reinstate the cognito session?
Apparently I need to do something more for amplify or cognito to realize the tokens are now there.

This is the list of items in storage:
[image: Local Storage]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should attempt to load it from storage if you call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser`.

Of course you are going to get into trouble sharing credentials across origins as the refresh token grant will fail for the second app using it.

Source: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/a047ce73abe98c3bf82e888c3afb4d2f911805f3/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L1191